# How to distribute different versions of the same app in IOS

Tags: ios, app-store, publishing

I need to have two different versions or more of the same  IOS app with new versions for ios7, ios6, like wise. So devices which is not compatible of handling the ios7 will get the ios6 version app. Is this possible, how will the app id be for such situation.

Comment: Its a bad idea to make two apps, one for iOS6 and other for iOS7. There is nothing stopping a user running iOS 7 to download iOS 6 version of the app. Apple itself may have issues with this kind of arrangement. Answers below are correct. Check your code with [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] and then do whatever you need to appropriately.

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 options here

1. Release 1 app with the same bundle identifier that has runtime checks for OS Version and acts accordingly
2. Make 3 targets of the same app with different bundle identifiers, names and deployment targets, and sell them separately on the iTunes store.

I would highly recommend implementing #1. You can check the iOS version at runtime using

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to have a lite version and a full version of your app that is fine just create two different targets in xcode.

For having a completely different versions for iOS I'm sorry but unless you do this in your code and change based on checking the iOS version being used this isn't possible to create different targets for different deployment versions (iOS versions). If you put your deployment target as iOS 6 it will also run on iOS 7 there is no way of stopping that and the same would be if it was set to iOS 5 it will run on iOS 6 and iOS 7 and it is your responsibility to make sure it does work on these iOS versions no one elses.

As an additional note from the 1st February all apps submitted to the Apple App Store Review process must be iOS 7 optimized https://developer.apple.com/news/index.php?id=12172013a

You can check the iOS version a couple of ways:

1) Many check the current device system version `[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];`

2) Are some like to check the `NSFoundationVersionNumber`

Comment: Comments have been removed. Threats are not welcome here. If you persist you will be suspended.

Comment: The comment was addressed at both parties - you and @coneybeare. If either of you think that something is wrong with a post *flag* it for moderator attention. Don't engage in arguments in comments.